# Difference between Rand and Jaccard similarity index?

Tags: validation, statistics, probability, similarity

What is the theoretical difference between Rand and Jaccard similarity/validation index?

I'm not interested in equations, but the interpretation of their difference.

I know Jaccard index neglects true negatives, but why? And what kind of impact does this have?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I worked with these in my Master's thesis in computational biology so hopefully I should be able to answer this in a way which helps you-

**The shorter version -**

J=TP/(TP+FP+FN) while R=(TP+TN)/(TP+TN+FP+FN)

Naturally, TN are neglected by Jaccard by definition. For very large datasets, the number of TN can be pretty huge, which was the case in my thesis. So, that term was driving all the analysis. When I shifted from rand index to Jaccard Index, I neglected the contribution of TN and was able to understand things better.

**The longer version-**

Rand and Jaccard Indices are more often used to compare Partitionings/clusterings than usual response characteristic statistics like senstivity/specificity etc. But they can in some sense be extended to the idea of a true positive or a true negative. Let's go over this in greater detail-

For a set of elements S={a1,a2....an}, we can define two different clustering algos X and Y which divide them into r clusters each - X1,X2...Xr clusters and Y1,Y2....Yr clusters. Combine all X clusters or all Y clusters and you will get your complete S set again.

Now, we define:-
A= the number of pairs of elements in S that are in the same set in X and in the same set in Y
B= the number of pairs of elements in S that are in different sets in X and in different sets in Y
C= the number of pairs of elements in S that are in the same set in X and in different sets in Y
D= the number of pairs of elements in S that are in different sets in X and in the same set in Y

Rand Index is defined as - R=(A+B)/(A+B+C+D)
Now look at things this way - Let X be your results from a diagnostic test, while Y are the actual labels on the data points. So, A,B,C,D then reduce to TP,TN,FP,FN (in that order). Basically, R reduces to the definition I gave above.

Now, Jaccard Index-

For two sets M,N Jaccard index disregards elements that are in different sets for both clustering algorithms X and Y i.e. it neglects B, which is true negatives.

J = (A)/(A+C+D) which reduces to J=(TP)/(TP+FP+FN).

And that's how the two statistics are fundamentally different. If you want more info on these, here's a pretty good paper, and a website which might be of use to you -

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.164.6189&rep=rep1&type=pdf

http://clusteval.sdu.dk/313/clustering_quality_measures/542

Hope this helps!